# Is it safe to use database table columns as form input names?

Tags: input

For example:

On the webpage the form has the following inputs:

```
<label>Member's Username</label>
<input type="text" name="mem_log_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['mem_log_name']; ?>" />
<label>Member's Password ID</label>
<input type="text" name="mem_log_pass" value="<?php echo $_POST['mem_log_pass']; ?>" />
```

Likewise

```
database name: db
Table name: members_log
column names: mem_ID (primary, autoincrement), mem_log_name(unique), mem_log_pass(INT)
```

Comment: i think there should not be any problem :)

Comment: What do you SQL statements look like?

Comment: IMO it's better not to ease the life of hackers so I'd do my best not to disclose the scheme of the database.

Comment: It all depends, what is your INSERT code? It may be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: I use PDO in my queries and bindValue/bindParams. I do extensive input sanitazing and validation in an attempt to prevent SQL injection - off course PDO takes care of much of that.... I was just wondering if it was a good practise

Comment: Then everything is fine. I personally often use same names as input ones, for fields in database. It's easies work a bit, and when saintazing properly, there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

offhand I can't think of a reason why not, except that you need to make sure to not write your code to open yourself up to let someone inject stuff into your DB. So, you can keep your labels uniform, but still not give anyone access to write or manipulate your inserts/updates/selects etc.